# Laravel multiple notifications type

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I want to have multiple notifications type in my web app. I've already done pretty fine notifying a user of a particular thing that occured; it works. What I want to do now is creating another notification type. As Laravel uses the same `notifications` table for all notifications as I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179100/how-to-create-multiple-notification-files-with-separate-notification-tables-for) I created another Notification class with the `php artisan make:notification` command. After setting it up, when triggered it works fine too: it is well recorded in the `notifications` database table with it specific 'type' mentioned in the `notifications` `type` column. Now the intended user should be able to receive both notifications.

My issue is how do I manage to get that specific notification shown to the user. With the first notification class implemented, all was working fine: the user get his notifications. With now two notifications type, whenever I try to display all notifications with a `@foreach(auth()->user()->notifications as $notification)` in the blade view like I was doing, I'm getting an error `Undefined index: EtudiantsChoixTheme` with `EtudiantsChoixTheme` being data I send to the user:

```
        $EtudiantsChoixTheme = [
            'id' => $idData,
                 ...
            'theme' => $themeData
        ];

        \Notification::send($user, new StudentChoosedThemeNotification($EtudiantsChoixTheme));
```

`StudentChoosedThemeNotification` being the first Notification class I've implemented. This error occurs only when I want to display notifications of a user which has received (user id in the `notifiable_id` field) the two Notification types. I tried what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179100/how-to-create-multiple-notification-files-with-separate-notification-tables-for) : `$user->notifications->filter(function($e) { $e->type == 'NewNotificationClass'})` but I'm getting an error :`syntax error, unexpected '}'`... I've also [tried](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#accessing-the-notifications) to display the notification type with `{{$notification->type}}` but this is only displayed for the users which has only one type of notification received. When a user receive more than one Notification it seems I can't anymore display those notifications.

How precisely may I retrieve the notification data of a particular notification type for a user in Laravel? Had anyone of you already did something like this? Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$notifications = $request
->user()
->notifications
->where('type', 'App\Notifications\CommentCreated')
->all();
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#available-methods

Comment: Do you know how to remove notification type class namespace and just use class basename? Thanks.

Comment: so by this user will get only commentCreated notificatin. what if i want only admin get this notification via mail and database, and for owner (role) he will get this notification via mail,database and sms.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.